# Is PIL (pillow) corrupting my image files?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

Here's the basic code:

```
file = "C:\DLS\sampleImage.jpg"
image = Image.open(file)
image.close()
print(str(image.width) + "x" + str(image.height))
```

Given a regular .jpg image file, I can open it fine.  After I run this script, the file size goes to 1KB (or likely less) and is completely corrupted.  These are all images I downloaded from Discogs.  They were fine to start.  In fact, the thumbnails all stayed valid because I didn't run this script on them.

Pillow: c:\python310\lib\site-packages (9.5.0)

Python: Python 3.10.4

I initially had this code running right after the download, but I began assuming that it was because Windows hadn't finished "writing" the file and I was messing with it too soon.  I tried time.sleep(5) as a test.  No good.  I setup a new run against the files *well* after the were downloaded.  Still corrupts them.  I'm not even trying to modify the image here at all.

Comment: What is `args` here?

Comment: @MichaelButscher  I changed the code for you.  I just didn't see the reason to include all the argument definitions for the function.

Comment: No, opening an image for reading cannot damage it.  Now, you are not protecting the backslashes in your filenames.  It's easy to make a filename mistake that way.  Use forward slashes and see if that changes things.

Comment: @TimRoberts  As a veteran programmer (30+ years), I would completely agree with your assessment.  However, it happened every time.   Wish I had a convenient way to screen cap a video.  It is most DEFINITELY doing it.  My separate script to open the files (nowhere near the download operation), does this same thing and then the file is damaged immediately after.

Comment: The implication is that Pillow is writing the file. So maybe you can open the *"Properties"* of an image file and make it *"read only"* then try it again. If Pillow is opening for writing it should fail.

Comment: What does a hex dump of the first, say, 256 bytes of the resulting file look like?